# Hi, how can I keep a user active when switching from one angular application to another without asking me to log in again?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have my login and I start the session but if it is not a user with an administrator role I have to redirect it to another application but I do not know how to keep the session active so that it does not log in again

Comment: Can you tell us more about the login implementation? Are you getting a token from an authentication server? Are both applications using the same login workflow/information?

Comment: It was already solved: it was not that the session was lost when the system changed, I was trying to enter a url that was already published from my localhost, in reality because there was no session in the public, therefore it sent me to login again

Answer (score 0):

In case you're not already doing it, you can store on your database (or where you handle authentication) a unique identifier bound to the open session.

When you navigate from an angular application to the other, simply pass the token so that the second application can automatically authenticate without knowing user/password or asking it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you use in authentication,  say you are using (Bearer token) in two apps and the users DB is shared also
you can follow these steps:

1. Send the generated token before redirection to the second App
2. In login page check if this token is valid if yes proceed to the home page else ; stay in login page
3. if the token is valid then send it to the whole authorized requests

Answer (score -1):

Probably the best way in your situation is to use localStorage. Before redirecting to another url, you'd have to store a key:value pair in localStorage like this:

```
AppComponent {

 public redirectToSecondApp() {
   localStorage.setItem('jwt', 'fgsdlkfgjwerg...2345234');
   this.redirectTo(this.url);
 }
}
```

Then on the second application's startup you can access this key:value pair like this

```
 SecondAppComponent {
  constructor() {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');
  }
}
```

The other way around is to use [query params](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-query-parameters) in combination with [activatedRoute](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information) on the second app (on the first app you set query params, on the second you can access these params by activatedRoute)

(If you use session-based authentication it may be a bit tricky, but I hope you got the general idea about localStorage. Good luck!)